# How To Change Applet Color

Tags: java, colors, applet, point

I need some help with this program I have to create for Uni. The problem is that the setColor and getColor methods do no work, and the line doesn't change color when I want it too.

What do I need to do to change the color of the line to red?

Cheers

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Shape extends JPanel {
static Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
Point controlPoint = new Point(0, 0);

Color colour = Color.BLACK;

public Shape() {
    this(startPoint);

}

public Shape(Point startPoint) {
    // initialise variable startPoint
    this.startPoint = startPoint;
    // execute methods setColour and setControlPoint
    setColor(colour);
    setControlPoint(controlPoint);
    // change startPoint
    startPoint.x = 50;
    startPoint.y = 50;

}

public void setColor(Color colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
    colour = Color.RED;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return colour;
}

public void setControlPoint(Point controlPoint) {
    controlPoint.x = 150;
    controlPoint.y = 150;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(colour);
    g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, controlPoint.x, controlPoint.y);
}
```

}

Comment: You should post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: What is the goal of your `setColor` method? The second line is a no-op, and as you invoke it in this part shown here, the first one does nothing, too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call repaint() after the color is set

```
public void setColor(Color colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
    colour = Color.RED;

    // Repaint so the component uses the new color
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: +1, whenever you change a property of oa component you need to repaint() the component as well.

Comment: Also remember to set visibility for your objects.

Comment: Swing components are visible by default, except for top level containers (JFrame, JDialog, JWindow...).

Comment: Though I used the original source code in the example above you should really be passing in Color.RED as a parameter. If you only ever want the line to be red then do what camickr suggests below.

Comment: Sorry to reply a bit late but even though I added the repaint() the component wont change colour. What is wrong?

Comment: Please add the full source code to this question.  Without it I have no idea what else may be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can get rid of the setColor() method.

Then you can use:

```
setForeground( colour );
```

to control the color of the line to be drawn.

The color of the Graphics object will be set to the foreground colour so you can also get rid of:

```
g.setColor( colour );
```